# How to list a JQuery file in an asp.net mvc bundleconfig.cs to include the minified version without the version number

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to list the minified version of JQuery in my bundleconfig.cs file without having to list the full name or include the version number.  The following works:

```
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
   }
```

And the following with the full file name and version works:

```
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"));
   }
```

But if I try to capture the minified version as shown below it does not work:

```
   public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));
   }
```

Is there a way to add the JQuery file to a bundle to include the minified version without having to specify the version of JQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you should also specfy in your Application_start() from Global.asax, the folowing line:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

This enables bundling and minification. If you set it to false or not set it all all, then it will not do bundling and minification.

Comment: The full bundle does have that. I only provide a small snippet to focus on the particular issue. Perhaps I'll expand the sample

Comment: I am using preprocessor directives. The sample I provided is for #if DEBUG are you saying that the directive block I have for #else which is where I have the optimization option rendered that when that logic kicks in Visual Studio will automatically select the mininified version of the JQuery file? I'll have to chek that